# selecting an element one before the previous from selected option with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, select

I want to access the value of the select option that one before the previous one of the selected one, meaning 2 away from the selected one. (sorry, it's hard to phrase it!)

For instance, if "4" is selected from here, I want to get the value of the option "2".

```
<option value ="1">1</option>
<option value ="2">2</option>
<option value ="3">3</option>
<option value ="4">4</option>
```

I know there is prev method for the immediately previous one, but how about the other ones?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when option values 2 or 1 are selected?

Comment: @MatthewJ oh, that's a good question! I should apply it to 3 and above. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var a = $('select option:selected').prev().prev().text();
    alert(a);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/NcPgV/

However, this returns nothing when the selection is 2 or lower.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can call [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) twice.

An alternative, more scalable solution is to use [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/). It returns elements ordered from the closest sibling outwards, so you can combine it with [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
var siblingValue = $("option:selected").prevAll().eq(1).val();
```

This way, you won't have to chain multiple calls to `prev()` if you want to move more than 2 options away from the selected one.

Answer (score 1):

The [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) function will get the preceding sibling for a given node; calling it twice will accomplish what you want.

```
var element = $("option[value='4']");
var prev2 = $(element).prev().prev();
alert(prev2.val());
//alerts 2
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hFw48/)